# How to add images to each canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 10 canvases on the same page. On each canvas I'm trying to add an existent image. Is this possible? I tried this next code but is not displaying any image:

```js
var numberOfPages = $('.draw_pages canvas').length;
   var i = 0;
   var counter = 0;
   for(i=0; i<numberOfPages; i++){
    counter++;
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_"+counter);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Hello World "+ counter, 110, 250);
     
     //add images to canvas
     var base_image = new Image();
     base_image.onload = function(){
   init();
  }
      base_image.src = '../images/page_1.png';
  function drawImage(){
      ctx.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, 575, 575);
  }
  function init(){
   drawImage();
  }
  
   
   }
```

I've also tried this way, but it works only when I hit enter key on the url of the browser and the text is being drawed:

```js
var numberOfPages = $('.draw_pages canvas').length;
   var i = 0;
   var counter = 0;
   for(i=0; i<numberOfPages; i++){
    counter++;
    console.log(counter);
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_"+counter);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Hello World "+ counter, 110, 250);
     
     //add images to canvas
     drawImage();
  function drawImage(){
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = '../jester/images/page_1.png';
    //base_image.onload = function(){
      ctx.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, 575, 575);
    //}
  }
   }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be simple! Use jquery .each() and do Your operations inside of it.

```js
$(function() {
  $('canvas').each(function() {
      var n = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
      var context = this.getContext('2d');
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-640-480-'+n+'.jpg';
      image.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 575, 575);
        context.font = '30px Arial';
        context.fillText('Hello World '+ n, 20, 20);      
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas_1"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas_2"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas_3"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. This works very well.

Comment: Happy to help. Hope You enjoyed (;